# Show Mainwindow in the right of the screen (Qt 5.1.0)

Tags: c++, qt, screen

I want to show my mainwindow in the right side of the screen.

I use this code  :

```
QRect r  = this->frameGeometry();   
r.moveRight(QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry());   
this->move(r.topRight());
```

And I receive this error :

> error: cannot call member function 'const QRect QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(int) const' without object

If I use 1024 instead `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry()` it works... But I don't want to initialize it staticly...

How can I dynamically reposition the window for different screen sizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry) is not a static function. You can use [QApplication::desktop()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#desktop) function to get a `QDesktopWidget` object:

```
QRect r  = this->frameGeometry();
r.moveRight(QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry());
```

You will have to put something else in the moveRight() function. You can't put a QRect there. Maybe what you want to do is:

```
QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
r.setLeft(r.center().x());
this->resize(r.width(), r.height());
this->move(r.topLeft());
```

Or if you don't want to resize your window:

```
QRect r = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
QRect main_rect = this->geometry();
main_rect.moveTopRight(r.topRight());
this->move(main_rect.topLeft());
```

Comment: I try that but I reveice this error : **error: no matching function for call to 'QRect::moveRight(const QRect)'**

Comment: Still Window is in the center of screen :(

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH İT WORKED ;)

Comment: we are working position of window.. But now I want to align right screen  :/

Comment: @MOC89 What do you mean?

Comment: I am working four days on this issue :(( ..  I want to make like that ; if I click any button there [İMAGE_1](http://u1308.hizliresim.com/1d/n/rq24n.png) , I want to expansion of the MainWindow like that [İMAGE_2](http://m1308.hizliresim.com/1d/n/rq27x.png)

Comment: I think we need to change width of mainwindow.

Comment: @MOC89 Yes, you set a new width to it and move it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the window in question is 800×800:

```
QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
move(QPoint((rec.width()-800)/2, (rec.height()-800)/2));
```